# Event bubbling with CaptureMouse() in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, draggable, event-bubbling

I'm writing a window program in Silverlight, meaning that the top bar of a popup has a draggable area, and within that draggable area, an "X" that closes the window. My drag function has a capturemouse() event which, when combined with the event bubbling that occurs, prevents the close function from being called. Here's the code:

```
private void close_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e){
            pop.IsOpen = false;
            hasFocus = true;
        }

        private void topBar_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Border item = sender as Border;
            mouseY = e.GetPosition(null).Y;
            mouseX = e.GetPosition(null).X;
            draggable = true;
            item.CaptureMouse();

        }

        private void topBar_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(draggable){
                double changeY = e.GetPosition(null).Y - mouseY;
                double changeX = e.GetPosition(null).X - mouseX;
                double top = changeY + (double)pop.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
                double left = changeX + (double)pop.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
                if(top<0){
                    top = 0;
                }
                if(left<0){
                    left = 0;
                }
                if(left>670){
                    left = 670;
                }
                if(top>450){
                    top = 450;
                }
                pop.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, top);
                pop.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, left);
                mouseY = e.GetPosition(null).Y;
                mouseX = e.GetPosition(null).X;
            }
        }

        private void topBar_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Border item = sender as Border;
            draggable = false;
            mouseY = -1;
            mouseX = -1;
            item.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
```

EDIT: here is the XAML for the entire popup:

```
<Popup x:Name="pop" Height="200" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Width="200" Height="200" Background="#FFFAFCFF" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#99666666" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#99F5F5F5" Offset="0.5"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#99666666" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Border x:Name="topBar" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Background="Crimson" Width="198" Height="20" MouseLeftButtonDown="topBar_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="topBar_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="topBar_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                <Image x:Name="close" Source="X.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,7,0" Height="11" Width="11" MouseLeftButtonUp="close_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
                            </Border>
                            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                <TextBlock Text="Printer info goes here..." />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
```

Comment: I assume the 'X' is a button, so when you click on the button, the Border is still the sender of the event? Do you have 'IsHitTestVisible" set to false on the button?

Comment: I don't have `IsHitTestVisible` declared anywhere in my code.

Comment: Could you show the xaml for the border and the 'X' button? I just want to see what events are defined.

Comment: I added the XAML, if you need anything else, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of your MouseCapture calls. When you set the mousecapture, the border is the only control that will be allowed to initiate mouse events. This means the image, while the mouse button is down, no longer triggers mouseevents.
Without the mousecapture it should work fine. Just for my curiosity, why do you set and release it?

I hope this helps.

Edit:

You can get the position of the mouseEvent and see if it falls in the image:

```
        var x = e.GetPosition(close).X;
        var y = e.GetPosition(close).Y;
        if (0 <= x && x <= 11 && 0 <= y && y <= 11)
        {
            //do the close call
        }
```

I haven't tested this code but it should be close to what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, it works fine without that, but the reason I do that is because when I don't have a set or release the window dragging is buggy. Is there any way to ensure that the close is called first?

Comment: The border and image will always be in the same location and have the same size so you could check and see if the mouse coordinates are inside the image and call the close function based on that.